# How to prevent a custom Mapbox callout automatically hide when zoom or panning on Map View

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I follow this article [Custom Call out](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/custom-callout/)

Every time when I zoom or panning on Mapbox View, the call out is automatically hide!

How to prevent this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to add two class variables to your CustomCalloutView class. Add these two lines before your init method:

```
var dismissesAutomatically: Bool = false
var isAnchoredToAnnotation: Bool = true
```

This seems to fix the problem of the Callout being dismissed, and allows the callout to follow the annotation.

However, this runs into a new problem where every time the map is panned/zoomed, the callout seems to drop down about 10 pixels. I'm still trying to figure this out. I have opened another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379788/mapbox-callout-moving-on-pan-zoom) to see if anybody knows how to solve the issue.

Comment: I just added some constraints. My whole callout was stored in an IBOutlet called content view, so I added `let centerX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
        let botCon = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: -10);
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([botCon, centerX])`

Answer (score 1):

As given above you need to add:

```
let dismissesAutomatically: Bool = false
let isAnchoredToAnnotation: Bool = true
```

so the callout does not drop down when panning you will also need to add:

```
override var center: CGPoint {
    set {
        var newCenter = newValue
        newCenter.y = newCenter.y - bounds.midY
        super.center = newCenter
    }
    get {
        return super.center
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you say which version of the Mapbox iOS SDK are you using? This bug should have been fixed for [3.4.0](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/3154). You may want to try the latest version of the SDK, if you aren't already using it.