# Mapbox Callout moving on Pan/Zoom.

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I have followed the guide [here](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/custom-callout/) to create custom Callout Views. I added two lines to the custom class:

```
var dismissesAutomatically: Bool = false
var isAnchoredToAnnotation: Bool = true
```

These seem to do the job when it comes to keeping the Callout View displayed when panning and zooming, and keeping it anchored to the annotation. However, The Callout seems to drop down about 20 pixels when the user pans or zooms.

Initial View when annotation is tapped, but before panning/zooming:

[image: Before Pan/Zoom]

View immediately after panning/zooming:

[image: View immediately after panning/zooming]

Answer (score 1):

From the Mapbox API docs for isAnchoredToAnnotation:

> A Boolean value indicating whether the callout view should be anchored to the corresponding annotation. You can adjust the callout view’s precise location by overriding -[UIView setCenter:]. The callout view will not be anchored to the annotation if this optional property is unimplemented.

In Swift that would be: `myView.center =`
Hope this helps.

EDIT :- 
Take a look at [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/draggable-views/) on the Mapbox website that describes how to implement draggable annotations. The interesting part is in the `setDragState` method where the drag state (an `MGLAnnotationViewDragState`) is tested. I'd suggest implementing the callout centre coordinate update in the `.dragging` case in a similar fashion to the way they have implemented the `startDragging()` and `endDragging()` functionality.

Comment: I tried setting the center of my CustomCalloutView in my MGLMapViewDelegate, `calloutViewFor annotation` method, but It doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I've added some more info to my answer. The callout's position needs to be updated continuously during the drag process and so I've referenced a possible solution to that. It might be worth asking why you need to implement annotation behaviour that the user wouldn't expect to see during normal map usage? Users are used to callouts disappearing when they drag and you could always have it reappear when the annotation is dropped again.